# c# elastic search nest how to output the document score

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I would like to output the score for each result from elastic search. But I'am unsure how I can get this.

Below is my current code for running a query:

```
  var searchResults = client.Search<Place>(s => s
             .From(0)
             .Size(5)
             .Explain(true)
             .TrackScores(true)
             .Query(q => q

                    .QueryString(fqqs1 => fqqs1
                        .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                            .Add("name", 5.0)
                        )
                        .Query("west midlands birmingham")
                    )

             )
             .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
             .Sort(sort => sort.OnField(f => f.id).Ascending())
       );

// Output the results to console
        Console.WriteLine("\nTotal Hits: " + searchResults.HitsMetaData.Hits.Count + " out of " + searchResults.HitsMetaData.Total);

        List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
        foreach (Place result in searchResults.Documents)
        {
            results.Add(new Result
            {
                woeid = Convert.ToInt32(result.id),
                name = result.name,
                admin1 = result.admin1,
                admin2 = result.admin2,
                type = result.type
            });
            Console.WriteLine(result.id + " > " + result.name + " > " + result.admin1 + " > " + result.admin2 + " > " + result.type); 
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

use the `.Hits` property collection on the `ISearchResponse<T>` - The collection contains the score for each document in the `.Score` property, as well as the document in the `.Source` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by score. eg: **Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())**

```
 var result = client.Search(q => q
                 .Index(your-index-name)
                 .From(0)
                 .Type("post")
                 .Fields("firstName","LastName")
                 .TrackScores(true)
                 .Size(12) 
                 .Query(SearchQuery)                           
                 .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
                );
```

Code sample for Nest 7

```
var sorts = new List<ISort>();
sorts.Add(new FieldSort { Field = "_score", Order = SortOrder.Descending });

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>()
            {
                Profile = true,
                From = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize,
                Size = pageSize,
                Version = true,
                Sort = sorts,
                Query = new MatchAllQuery()
                Aggregations = aggrigations
            };

 var searchResponse = _client.Search<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(searchRequest);
```